# Organizing dates and holidays in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**Scenario:** I have one with different columns of data, and another single dataframe with lists of dates.

**Example of dataframe1:**

```
iterationcount     datecolumn     list
  iteration5                       1
  iteration5                       2
  iteration3                       2
  iteration3                       2
  iteration4                       33
  iteration3                       4
  iteration1                       5
  iteration2                       3
  iteration5                       2
  iteration4                       22
```

**Example of dataframe2:**

```
iteration1 01.01.2018   26.01.2018  30.03.2018
iteration2 01.01.2018   30.03.2018  02.04.2018  25.12.2018  26.12.2018
iteration3
iteration4 01.01.2018   15.01.2018  19.02.2018
iteration5 01.01.2018   19.02.2018  30.03.2018  21.05.2018  02.07.2018  06.08.2018  03.09.2018  08.10.2018  12.11.2018
```

The second dataframe is a list of holidays for each of the iterations. And it will be used to fill the second column of the first dataframe

**Constraints:** For each iteration of the first dataframe the user will select a month and year: the script will then find the first date of that month. If that date is on the list of dates of dataframe2 for that iteration, then pick the next working date based on the program calender.

**Ex:** User selects January 2018, code returns 01/01/2018. For the first iteration, that date is a holiday, so pick the next workday, in this case 02/01/2018, and then input this date to all of dataframe1 corresponding to that iteration:

```
   iterationcount     datecolumn     list
      iteration5                       1
      iteration5                       2
      iteration3                       2
      iteration3                       2
      iteration4                       33
      iteration3                       4
      iteration1      02/01/2018       5
      iteration2                       3
      iteration5                       2
      iteration4                       22
```

Then move to the next iteration (some iterations will have the same calendar dates).

**Code:** I have tried multiple approaches so far, but could not achieve the result. The closest I think I got was with:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import os
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
import glob

## Get Adjustments
mypath3 = "//DGMS/Desktop/Uploader_v1.xlsm"
ApplyOnDates = pd.read_excel(open(mypath3, 'rb'), sheet_name='Holidays')   

# Get content
mypath = "//DGMS/Desktop/Uploaded"
all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(mypath, "*.xls*"))
contentdataframes = []
contentdataframes2 = []

for f in all_files:
    df = pd.read_excel(f)
    df['Name'] = os.path.basename(f).split('.')[0].split('_')[0]
    df['ApplyOn']= ''
    mask = df.columns.str.contains('Base|Last|Fixing|Cash')
    c2 = df.columns[~mask].tolist()
    df = df[c2]
    contentdataframes.append(df)

finalfinal = pd.concat(contentdataframes2)    

for row in finalfinal.Name.itertuple():
    datedatedate = datetime.datetime(2018, 01, 1)
    if (pd.np.where(ApplyOnDates.Index.str.contains(finalfinal(row)).isin(datedatedate) = True:
        datetouse = datedatedate + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    else:
        datetouse = datedatedate
    finalfinal['ApplyOn'] =  datetouse
```

**Question:** Basically, my main trouble here is being able to match the rows in both dataframes and search the date in the column of the holidays dataframe. Is there a proper way to do this?

Obs: I was able to achieve a similar result directly in vba, by using the functions of excel (vlookup, match...), the problem is that doing in excel for the amount of data basically crashes the file every time.

Comment: It is quite confusing that you seem to mix date formats. In your example you have dates as e.g. `02.01.2018` for January 2nd, but then you suddenly have `01/02/2018`.

Comment: @Graipher my mistake when writing the question, will fix it now.

Answer (score 0):

so you want to basically merge the column of dataframe2 to dataframe1 right? Try to use merge:

```
newdf = pd.DataFrame.merge(dataframe1, dataframe2, left_on='iterationcount', 
right_on='iterationcount', how='inner', indicator=False)
```

That should give you a new frame.

Comment: Not quite so, In dataframe2, the date to be added will be the first of the month, if it is not a holiday according to dataframe1. So basically, I will not merge the dates of the holidays dataframe, I will use it to change the first day of the month.